# Os prefixos CSS variam de propriedade para propriedade?

Tags: css

Estava dando uma olhada nos prefixos e com um monte de código para colocá-los (eu não tinha o costume de usar os prefixos até que comecei a usar as novas propriedades do CSS, triste) e fui dar uma olhada em ferramentas online para fazer o trabalho duro.

Achei esse site muito interessante: http://pleeease.io/play/. Quando eu coloco algumas propriedades como o `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`, ele só coloca dois prefixos: `-webkit-` e `-ms-`. Percebi que os prefixos realmente são importantes quando o *transform* só funcionou no IE com eles, mas quero saber o motivo da ferramenta não incluir todos os prefixos.

Eles variam de propriedade para propriedade?

Comment: Quando uma propriedade ainda não está 100% padronizada, mas os fornecedores de *browsers* querem inclui-la imediatamente, sem esperar o fim da padronização, eles normalmente usam um prefixo próprio (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, `-o-`, ...) para - caso a propriedade mude no futuro - não quebrar código antigo que já usava ela tal como foi implementada (eu acho). À medida que a padronização vai sendo concluída, o prefixo torna-se desnecessário, pois o *browser* passa a aceitar a versão padronizada também, sem o prefixo (esta já implementada em conformidade com a especificação final).

Comment: Tinha lido sobre isso enquanto pesquisava, é algo bem interessante de saber. Deve ter sido isso que aconteceu com o `border-radius`, antes alguns navegadores não exibiam sem o prefixo, agora já padronizou. Por precaução colocarei as novas propriedades com todos os prefixos :)